# Why FB returns different results of the same object for different access tokens?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

There is [Event](https://www.facebook.com/events/321074447988833/) on Facebook. I'm using FQL to retrieve information and results are different for different access tokens.

 Select query

```
select eid, name, start_time, end_time, update_time, timezone, from event where eid in (321074447988833)
```

1)access token was [generated](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=select%20eid,%20name,%20pic_big,%20description,%20privacy,%20start_time,%20end_time,%20update_time,%20timezone,%20location,%20venue%20from%20event%20where%20eid%20in%20%28321074447988833%29):
 
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20eid,%20name,%20pic_big,%20description,%20privacy,%20start_time,%20end_time,%20update_time,%20timezone,%20location,%20venue%20from%20event%20where%20eid%20in%20(321074447988833)&access_token=XXXXX

result:

```
"start_time": "2012-09-12",
"end_time": null,
```

2) Real user access token:
result:

```
"start_time": 1347440400,
"end_time": 1347526800,
```

Why on the first example we don't have "end_time" (it's right) but on the second we have it and the difference between start_time and end_time is one day. So it looks like event takes 2 days accept of one.

Comment: I think you should not post real access tokens in the internet.

Comment: Please, write normal SELECT-query, not urls! it is hard to read with `%20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Graph API Facebook application must have the [Events Timezone Migration](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/01/platform-migration--events-timezone-support/) enabled.

The current method is to return a UNIX timestamp of the event's time as though it takes place in Pacific Time converted to GMT.

With the migration enabled, Facebook now returns an [ISO-8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) formatted date string with time and timezone.

The migration is currently scheduled to be rolled out to all apps in December.